# Django DataError in /register/ 'interger out of range'

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to make a custom registration system with django, but when i submit my registeration form, i get a DataError at /register/, 'integer out of range'. What could be the problem

Django says the error is from this file "forms.py"

P.S; im using postgres database

my code:

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from .models import recordBuddyUser
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    companyname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'company-nam',
            'placeholder': 'company Name',
            'id': 'exampleInputcompanyName',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companyadministrator = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'administrator',
            'id': 'exampleAdminName',
            'placeholder': 'company Admin',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companyphone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'maxlenght': '15',
            'type': 'number',
            'name': 'companyphonenumber',
            'placeholder': 'company Phone',
            'id': 'examplecompanyPhoneNumber',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companyemail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'email',
            'name': 'company-email',
            'id': 'exampleInputEmail',
            'placeholder': 'Email Address',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companypassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password',
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'id': 'exampleInputPassword',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companypasswordconfirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'confirm-password',
            'id': 'exampleRepeatPassword',
            'placeholder': 'Repeat Password',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = recordBuddyUser
        fields = ('companyname', 'companyemail', 'companyphone',
                  'companyadministrator', 'companypassword', 'companypasswordconfirm')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['companyname'].lower()
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(companyname=username)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This company name '{username}' already exists !!")
        return username

    def clean_adminname(self):
        adminname = self.cleaned_data['companyadministrator'].lower()
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(
            companyadministrator=adminname)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This Admin name '{adminname}' already exists !!")
        return adminname

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['companyemail'].lower()
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(companyemail=email)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This company email '{email}' already exists !!")
        return email

    def clean_phonenumber(self):
        phonenumber = self.cleaned_data['companyphone']
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(
            companyphonenumber=phonenumber)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This company phone number '{phonenumber}' already exists!!")
        return phonenumber

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm-password')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Your passwords don't match.")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = recordBuddyUser.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['companyname'],
            self.cleaned_data['companyemail'],
            self.cleaned_data['companyadministrator'],
            self.cleaned_data['companyphone'],
            self.cleaned_data['companypassword'],
        )
        print ('New user saved')
        return user


class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    companyemail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'email',
            'name': 'company-email',
            'id': 'exampleInputEmail',
            'aria-describedby': 'emailHelp',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Email Address...',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    companypassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'type': 'password',
            'name': 'password',
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'id': 'exampleInputPassword',
            'class': 'form-control rounded-pill btn-user p-4 form-control-user'
        }
    )
    )
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
        attrs={

            'type': 'checkbox',
            'id': 'customCheck',
            'name': 'remember-me',
            'class': 'custom-control-input'
        }
    )
    )
    class Meta:
        model = recordBuddyUser
        fields = ('companyemail', 'companypassword')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['companyemail'].lower()
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(companyemail=email)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This company email '{email}' already exists !!")
        return email

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['companyname'].lower()
        recordBuddy_user = recordBuddyUser.objects.filter(companyname=username)
        if recordBuddy_user.count():
            raise ValidationError(f"This company name '{username}' already exists !!")
        return username

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['confirm-password']

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Your passwords don't match.")
        return password2

    def remember_me(self):
        remember_me = self.cleaned_data['remember_me']
        # remember_me = True

        if remember_me:

            # 2 weeks
            self.request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
            settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

The django traceback highlights this portion of code as the buggy one, i don't really know what to do here.

Traceback code:

```
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (integer out of range ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/views.py in register_view
            regform.save() …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/forms.py in save
            self.cleaned_data['companypassword'], …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/models.py in create_user
        user.save(using=self._db) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py in save
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
                force_update, using, update_fields, …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _save_table
            results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _do_insert
            using=using, raw=raw, …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
                cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
            return super().execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__
                raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
```

The regform.save() is just from my views.py but the other two are from the snippet above.

Below is my custom User model which i renamed to recordBuddyUser, I wanted to specify my own fields in the database although now I think of it I might have gone over board with it. Also i put the admin-user fields inside the same model (recordBuddyUser) as the regular fields i hope thats alright.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    PermissionsMixin,
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
)


# Custom models to override django default User and handle all User intercations

class User_manager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, companyname, companyemail, companyadministrator, companyphonenumber, companypassword):
        companyemail = self.normalize_email(companyemail)

        user = self.model(companyname=companyname, companyemail=companyemail,
                          companyadministrator=companyadministrator, companyphonenumber=companyphonenumber,
                          companypassword=companypassword,
                          )

        user.set_password(companypassword)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, admin_username, admin_email, admin_gender, admin_password, admin_position):
        user = self.create_user(admin_username=admin_username, admin_email=admin_email,
                                admin_gender=admin_gender, admin_position=admin_position, admin_password=admin_password
                                )

        # user.set_password(admin_password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class recordBuddyUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    ''' This model handles the details of users on Aqua Buddy '''
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    companyemail = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default=None)
    companyphonenumber = models.IntegerField()
    companypassword = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default=None)
    companyadministrator = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # companylogo = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True)
    dateregistered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # companyletterhead = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True)

    # recordBuddy Admin fields

    dateregistered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    admin_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default=None, unique=True)
    admin_position = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    admin_username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    admin_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=2083, default=None, blank=True)

    gender_choices = [("M", "Male"), ("F", "Female"), ("O", "Others")]
    admin_gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices,
                                    default="M", max_length=1, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["admin_username", "admin_email", "admin_position"]
    USERNAME_FIELD = "companyname"
    objects = User_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.companyname
```

I can't tell what is missing but offcourse the computer isn't wrong.

Comment: This is not the full traceback. The line stating the error is missing.

Comment: Not sure what the answer to this is without the full traceback, but I notice you have a typo `'maxlenght': '15'` under companyphone. May lead to errors down the line.

Comment: Thanks @Cm0295, i didn't even see that. Ive also added the full Traceback to the question.

Comment: You sure the arguments in the call to `recordBuddyUser.objects.create_user()` match those expected? You should add your model's code to the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ivissani, I have added my custom model to the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit seems to be the value in `companyphonenumber` field as it is declared as an `IntegerField`. You may be passing a full international number, something like 541112345678 that clearly [exceeds the maximum value accepted by `IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#integerfield).

You will need to change that field to another type, probably best is some kind of `CharField` like the one [provided by the django-phone-field package](https://pypi.org/project/django-phone-field/).